# Vue google Map Info window

Tags: vue.js

i have a vue app that showing google map by using vue2-google-map.
but i have a problem with to implement maps.infowindow to my marker because there are lack of vuejs stuff reference source.

this is my code for marker template :

```
      <GmapMap ref="mapRef"
        :center="{lat: 3.974341, lng: 102.438057}"
        :zoom="7"
        class="gmap"
      >
         <GmapMarker
          :key="index"
          v-for="(location, index) in markers"
          :position="location"
          :draggable="true"
          icon="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/map-pin.png"
         />
</GmapMap>
```

this is the script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      markers: [],
      infowindow: [],
    };
  },
async setMarker() {
  const { data } = await LocationRepository.getData(); //get data from api
  this.tempLatLong = data; 
  this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    this.markers = [];
    this.infowindow = [];
    const bounds = new this.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tempLatLong.length; i += 1) {
      const lati = parseFloat(this.tempLatLong[i].latitude);
      const long = parseFloat(this.tempLatLong[i].longitude);
      const location = new this.google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
      bounds.extend(location);

      const marker = 
        {
          lat: lati, lng: long
        }
      this.markers.push(marker);
      //this is where the problem occur.
     const content = '<div id="content">'+'<p>test</p>' +'</div>'
      this.infowindow.push(content)
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panTo({ lat: 3.974341, lng: 102.438057 });
  });
},
```

i referring to google map documentation about the infowindows but don't have any idea how to implement it into this code. can someone teach me how to use this infowindow in vuejs map.

Comment: please show your complete <template>.
have your wrapped <GmapMap> around the Marker?

Comment: done i have edited it and add the wrapper

Comment: and? it worked?

Comment: the infowindow part  not worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i have a working example from one of my projects. the data for the lat an lng comes from veux store. so you have to modify these

```
<template>
<GmapMap
    :center="getCenterPosition"
    :zoom="getZoomLevel"
    map-type-id="roadmap"
    style="width: 100%; height: 600px"
>
    <GmapMarker
        v-for="(m, index) in loadedDealers"
        :key="index"
        :position="{ lat: m.lat, lng: m.lng }"
        :clickable="true"
        :draggable="false"
        @click="openInfoWindowTemplate(index)"
        :icon="{ url: require('./test.png') }"
    />
    <gmap-info-window
        :options="{
          maxWidth: 300,
          pixelOffset: { width: 0, height: -35 }
        }"
        :position="infoWindow.position"
        :opened="infoWindow.open"
        @closeclick="infoWindow.open=false">
        <div v-html="infoWindow.template"></div>
    </gmap-info-window>
</GmapMap>
```

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        infoWindow: {
          position: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
          open: false,
          template: ''
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'getDealers',
            'getCenterPosition',
            'getZoomLevel',
        ]),
        loadedDealers() {
            return this.getDealers
        }
    },
    methods: {
        openInfoWindowTemplate(index) {
            const { lat, lng, name, street, zip, city } = this.loadedDealers[index]
            this.infoWindow.position = { lat: lat, lng: lng }
            this.infoWindow.template = `<b>${name}</b><br>${street}<br>${zip} ${city}<br>`
            this.infoWindow.open = true
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. it perfectly worked and i needed to change some code to match with my data.